# Como evitar que o usuário entre com um ponto "." antes de algum número?

Tags: android

Estou usando o `TextWatcher` para fazer outras persistências, mas travei nesta parte, estou pegando um valor `double` e utilizando ele para vários cálculos então não posso receber o valor ".55" por exemplo.

Se eu não precisasse fazer cálculos, o Android colocaria o `0` antes do ponto automaticamente para mim. Alguém sabe como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Se você está fazendo cálculos com **double**, então por padrão, números com **"."** na frente são aceitos e não atrapalham o cálculo. Mas se você quiser proibir o uso do **"."** antes de um número você pode usar [expressões regulares](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar, para cálculos matemáticos, o *BigDecimal*. Além de trabalhar com precisão, possui uma boa interação com views.

Tente isto:

```
String strValue = myTextView.getText().toString();
BigDecimal decimalValue = new BigDecimal(valueStr.replace('.', ','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso você informe o tipo de dado no xml do editText pode resolver seu problema?

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```